# Mysql unknown column in subquery works

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

There are three tables - `mapping_hospital_procedure`, `master_hospital` and `master_procedure`.

`master_hospital` contains an `id` column to identify each hospital.

`master_procedure` also contains an `id` column for the same purpose, i.e, to identify each procedure.

`mapping_hospital_procedure` is used to map hospitals to medical procedures and contains columns `hid` (hospital id) and `pid`(procedure id) besides other columns. Now, if I run this query :

`SELECT hid FROM master_procedure`

it doesn't work as you would expect because there is no `hid` column in `master_procedure`. But if I put this query in a sub-query, it works fine. Like this way, for example -

`SELECT hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure WHERE pid = (SELECT hid FROM master_procedure)`

But it shouldn't work as there is no column named `hid` in `master_procedure`. It should give the same Unknown column error as is the case with the previous query. Can anyone explain why or how this works?

Thank you.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218871/subquery-gives-no-error-for-a-non-existing-column-with-the-same-name-as-in-the-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope issue. You sub-query has access to the main-query's columns.

Since hid isn't found in the sub-query table, it will step out and look for it in the main query - there it's found in mapping_hospital_procedure table.

```
SELECT hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure
WHERE pid = (SELECT hid FROM master_procedure)
```

Is the same as

```
SELECT mhp.hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure mhp
WHERE mhp.pid = (SELECT mhp.hid FROM master_procedure mp)
```

Lesson now learned: Always qualify your columns!

**EDIT**: " *This should at least be a logical error giving incorrect output, right?*"

Yes, that query doesn't make much sense.

If the master_procedure table contains no rows at all, the `mhp.pid = (SELECT mhp.hid FROM master_procedure mp)` will be false. No rows at all are returned.

If the master_procedure table contains 2 rows or more, the "*Subquery returns more than 1 row*" exception should be raised. (Since it's a `=` comparison. Use `IN` to avoid this problem.)

If the master_procedure table contains exactly 1 row, the `mhp.pid = (SELECT mhp.hid FROM master_procedure mp)` condition evaluates to *true* if mhp.pid is not null, and the row is returned from mapping_hospital_procedure. If mhp.pid is null, the row isn't returned.

---

What you really want to do is probably:

```
SELECT mhp.hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure mhp
WHERE mhp.pid IN (SELECT mp.id FROM master_procedure mp)
```

Comment: So, in the subquery here, how is mhp.hid being accessed from master_procedure since its values don't exist in that table. This should at least be a logical error giving incorrect output, right?

Answer (score 1):

With that query you are actually doing a natural join. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php

The database parser is smart enough to translate your query into a join.
Your query:

```
SELECT hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure 
WHERE pid = (SELECT hid FROM master_procedure)
```

Is basically the same as:

```
SELECT hid FROM mapping_hospital_procedure 
NATURAL JOIN master_procedure 
WHERE pid = hid
```

Comment: I do not think that this is a good answer. First of all, any optimisation by the engine is done **after** checking the syntax, not before. Secondly, natural join requires identically named columns in both tables, which do not exists here. The answer from the dba site seems to be more accurate.